# Image Path for xaml?

Tags: xaml, path, expression-blend

I have an unique image that I want to draw inside expression blend using the Path data property and class, how can I extract the path from a image? It will be impossible to draw it to perfection, what software tool can I use to get the path?

Comment: Is it a Vector image made in something like Adobe Illustrator? If so it's easy, if not you'll have to at least make it a Vector image.

Comment: I have the same question.  have researched enough to know you need a vector image. In blend I added my vector image to Image control `<Image x:Name="image" Source="/Assets/Pivots/Icon.svg"/>`. Selecting Object>Path>Convert to Path  is disabled? I tested this on a Rectangle control and it worked, though. How did you solve this?